# Arithmetic division in relational algebra

Tags: select, relational-algebra

I have an SQL request:

```
SELECT table1.nr1 / NULLIF(table2.nr2, 0) as percentage
```

and I want to write this in relational algebra.

Is it possible to represent arithmetic division in relational algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this course of the University of Rochester](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/relations/algebra.html) relational algebra can be defined as

> a formal system for manipulating relations
>
> - Operands of this algebra are relations.
> - Operations of this algebra include the usual set operations (since relations are sets of tuples), and special operations defined for relations
>
>   - selection
>   - projection
>   - join

It's an algebra on relations and there is no representation of numbers. If you want to use arithmetic on numbers you have to use an extended formalism such as [Safe Database Queries with Arithmetic Relations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=163934F8C26C47A01CBE221BCA9692B9?doi=10.1.1.48.4845&rep=rep1&type=pdf).